# Laravel with Vue loading

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Laravel app which has Vue on front-end. I have a feeling I am overcomplicating it because I need to have few modals available on click from sidebar, which have a few select dropdowns. The data for dropdown list comes from the DB, which means that on loading each page I need to make 10 new ajax calls to fetch data which was already fetched one page before.

So for example:

```
    <project-modal 
        fetch-customers-url="{{ url('/api/v1/modals/customers') }}" 
        fetch-templates-url="{{ url('/api/v1/modals/templates') }}"
        fetch-project-statuses-url="{{ url('/api/v1/modals/project/statuses') }}"
        post-project-url="{{ route('project.store') }}">
    </project-modal>
    <task-modal 
        fetch-task-types-url="{{ url('/api/v1/modals/task/types') }}"
        fetch-task-statuses-url="{{ url('/api/v1/modals/task/statuses') }}"
        fetch-priorities-url="{{ url('/api/v1/modals/priorities') }}"
        post-task-url="{{ route('task.store') }}">
    </task-modal>
```

I was thinking about throwing everything in a session and pulling data from there if available but I don't think it is a good design, and even without it, there is an issue with data syncing that way.

How can I speed it up?

Comment: Is your app a single page application If so you can check out Vuex to store data from one page to another. As a second note if you have a cache mechanism implemented you could fetch all data in 1 request. I would also add that you could define the routes in constants rather than props because it could grow and can be hard to manage (single responsability)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It is not a SPA, it is an admin panel